# Heatplot/enrichGO, fold change display & order of genes

Tags: r, annotations, heatmap, rna-seq

Hello I'm working on the heatplot function offered in enrichPlot GO over-representation test (in R).
I was wondering if I could get some help with the following issues:

1. In what format should the 'geneList' in the 'foldChange=geneList' specification be? I can only get black and white results & not the colour scaled ones -When I tried to add the list of my DE genes (in my case 'fpkm_allGDE_up_345$Ens_ID_merge') I was getting the message:'Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale'.
   It only worked when I set 'foldChange=fpkm_allGDE_up$FOLD_CHANGE' but then with no colorscale.
2. Is it possible to rank the genes on the x axis so as that genes associated with more GO terms (of the ones indicated) are first?

**Here's what I tried:**

```
egoall_up <- enrichGO(gene          = fpkm_allGDE_up_345$Ens_ID_merge, #DEgenes_posttreatment
                      universe      = fpkm_allG_345$Ens_ID_merge,       #all genes expressed 
                      keyType       = "ENSEMBL",
                      OrgDb         = org.Hs.eg.db,
                      ont           = "ALL",
                      pAdjustMethod = "BH",
                      pvalueCutoff  = 0.01,
                      qvalueCutoff  = 0.05,
                      readable      = TRUE)

>heatplot(egoall_up, foldChange=fpkm_allGDE_up$FOLD_CHANGE, 
            showCategory=10)
```

[image]

```
head(fpkm_allGDE_up)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured this out already but I ran into the same issue. What worked for me was to change my 'geneList' into a named numeric vector.

To do this I took the gene names from my data frame and the Fold Change values and used the 'setNames' function.

ie
geneList<- setNames(mydf$foldchange,
mydf$Genes)

when you put this into the heatplot() function it works like a charm!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).